# Polynomial equation solver in Ruby

Tags: ruby, mathematics

I've written a small function for solving simple quadratic equations:

```
class EquationSolver
  def solve(x, *args)
    args.reverse.map.with_index { |coefficient, index| coefficient * x ** index }.reduce { |result, element| result + element }
  end
end
```

To calculate  `f(3)` for `f(x)=3x3−2x2−x+5`, one would write:

```
puts EquationSolver.new.solve(3, 3, -2, -1, 5)
```

However, is there a more elegant version of my function, more like `reduce.with_index` or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some notes:

- If you use a OOP approach, it seems more logical to use methods.
- Use arrays to group values that go together.
- I don't think *solve* is the correct term, that's when you are finding the roots of a function, here you're just *evaluating* it at a given point.

I'd write:

```
class Polynomial
  attr_accessor :coefficients 

  def initialize(coefficients)
    self.coefficients = coefficients.reverse
  end

  def evaluate(x)
    coefficients.map.with_index { |k, power| k * (x**power) }.reduce(0, :+)
  end
end

polynomial = Polynomial.new([3, -2, -1, 5])
puts polynomial.evaluate(3) #=> 65
```

Comment: Pretty good. Btw, I think you don't need the 0 in `reduce(0, :+)`.

Comment: @AlexPopov: Well, it's just to consider the case `f(x) = 0`.

Comment: Good point, didn't think about that.

Comment: Btw, if you have `zero = Polynomial.new 0`, the code throws `undefined method \`reverse' for 0:Fixnum (NoMethodError)`.

Comment: zero = Polynomial.new [0]

Comment: Yes, I figured that out, or the other option being `def initialize(*coefficients)`.

Comment: @Alex: Yes. Personally I don't like this because it makes difficult to add extra arguments. IMHO the coefficients should be grouped, and an array is the most obvious way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a more elegant version. Here it is:

```
class EquationSolver
  def solve(x, *args)
    args.reverse.each_with_index.reduce(0) { |result, (coefficient, index)| result + coefficient * x ** index }
  end
end
```

It's possible to do this because iterator methods like `each_with_index`, when called without a block, return an Enumerator object on which you can call all the methods of the Enumerable.

In fact, an even shorter solution is obtained by using a variation of reduce to use a symbolic operator:

```
class EquationSolver
  def solve(x, *args)
    args.reverse.map.with_index { |coefficient, index| coefficient * x ** index }.inject(:+)
  end
end
```

Comment: 10x, I had figured out the first version you proposed, but I didn't pass a `0` to `reduce` as a starting parameter, so it was giving me `no implicit conversion of Fixnum into Array`

Comment: Yep, it tends to happen. I'd any day prefer my second variation since it makes for an easy reading.